# Sum of $\binom ni$, where $i$ goes from $0$ to $k < n$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, summation, binomial-coefficients

I wonder what the value of this sum is:

$$S = \sum_{i=0}^k \binom ni$$

When $k=n$, then $S = 2^n$, but what if $k<n$?

Comment: An incomplete beta function.  There is not a simple expression without the sum, but you may find related information at [OEIS A008949](https://oeis.org/A008949)

Comment: @Henry I have no idea what that is but I will google it xD

Comment: It may not help.  One approximation (not particularly good, but better when $k$ is nearer $\frac n2$)  is $2^n \Phi \left(\frac{2k+1-n}{\sqrt{n}}\right)$ using the cumulative distribution function of a standard normal distribution.